# How do I construct a python requests post given an HTML form tag?

Tags: python, html, forms, python-requests, multipartform-data

Here's the entirety of the `<form>` tag of the actual webpage I'm trying to emulate.

```
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"  value="8388608">
<table class="form" style="font-size: 100%;">
</table>
<br>
<table class="form" style="font-size: 100%;">
<tr><th><label for="file">File</label></th><td>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="50">
</td></tr><tr><td>-or-</td></tr><tr><th><label for="url">Image URL</label></th><td>
<input name="url" type="text" id="url" size="50"><tr><td>
<input type="submit" value="submit" accesskey="s">
</td><td>
<label>[ <input type= "checkbox" name="forcegray"> ignore colors ]</label> <label>[ <input type="checkbox" name="mask-explicit"> mask explicit images ]</label>
</td></tr></table>
<ul><li>Supported file types are JPEG, PNG and GIF</li>
<li>Maximum file size: 8192 KB</li>
<li>Maximum image dimensions: 7500x7500</li>
<li>Image database updates every hour - last updated Jan 19 2016 at 18:22 EST
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

I've read many different examples using the `files=<dict>` or `data=<dict>` parameters of `requests.post`, and how to pass `open("filename.ext", "rb")` when dealing with multipart/form-data, but I'm still having difficulty understanding how to take these examples, backwards engineer them, and apply them to my own needs. Specifically, how do I know what HTML tag attributes such as `id` and `name` apply to what fields in the `requests.post` parameters? If the return content is different when using `requests.post` than using a normal web browser, what should I look to tweak in my code, or what more info should I pass?

I'm very comfortable when it comes to general coding and understanding of the information passed and returned, but web requests feel like a foreign language to me.

Comment: `POST` use only `name` - if you have `name="url"` then you need `data={"ulr": ... }`. BTW: you can use "Developer Tools" in Chrome or "Firebug" in Firefox to see what data is send by browser to server when you press "Submit".

Comment: Thanks I'll try to use this info.

Comment: as I said before `POST` use only `name` - `id` is used by `CSS`.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit slow at reading that, I first interpreted `name="url"` as a `requests.post` parameter

Comment: if you have `name="url"` in HTML then you have to use `data={"url": ... }` in requests.  And see `file` examples in documentation http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: It's still giving me a response page different than I'd get in the web browser. Response code is 200, but the content is different.

Comment: btw: you can use `http://httpbin.org/post` to test your script. This page will send back to you what it get from your script and you can compare it with information from Firebug.

Comment: use `Firebug` or `Developer Tools` to see what exactly is send by browser. Then use `http://httpbin.org` in your script to see what your script is sending - and then you can compare it.

Comment: it can be other problems - server can check `user-agent` header or `cookies `

Comment: it is easier when you put in question page address.